# gem install rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, typeerror

Ok, so I'm new to Ruby and Rails, and seem to have broken stuff. I was trying to install rails by doing the command `gem install rails`, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 31.139 given
```

I have uninstalled rvm by using `rvm implode` and reinstalled RVM and everything but when I get to installing rails, I get that error, every time.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using, and which version of Rails are you trying to install?

Comment: I am using 1.9.2 and trying to install the latest rails (3.0.4, I believe)

Comment: Try installing rails 3.0.7 as described here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec:install_ruby, this worked for me on Ubuntu Maverick.

Comment: Interesting, I got it installed correctly, but when I run `rails -v` I get this:

`/Users/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Users/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
 from /Users/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1276:in `gem'
 from /Users/USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your rvm install? I'd try completely removing rvm (rm -rf ~/.rvm) and reinstalling, double-checking each step is successful and that you're adding the correct line to .bash_profile.

Comment: odd still isn't working. I completely removed RVM and reinstalled it, but when trying to install a gem for example `gem install autotest` it spits that error again

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove all the gem sources you have and add https://rubygems.org/ instead. Note that http://gems.rubyforge.org/ and http://gems.github.com are permanently dead and should be removed. You can list your sources by running:

```
gem sources
```

You should get something like this:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

//gems.rubyforge.org/
//gems.github.com
```

1) Delete all sources:

```
gem sources -r http://gems.rubyforge.org/
gem sources -r http://gems.github.com
```

2) Add the right source:

```
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

Hope this helps!